How to stop acquireTokenWithDeviceCode?
I'm using MSAL in an Android application. I'm using device-authentication-flow. It works fine.
My app calls acquireTokenWithDeviceCode, shows the url and devicecode and lets the user login.
However, the user could choose not to log-in.
So, in that case I have to stop MSAL (to stop MSAL from wasting bandwidth whilst it's pinging for confirmation).
In dotnet there seems to be a CancellationToken, but in Android I haven't found it.
How to cancel acquireTokenWithDeviceCode? How to tell MSAL to cancel the flow?
